# How can Matlab compute the roughness along the boundary of an edge?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How can Matlab determine the roughness along the boundary of an edge? For example, how can Matlab determine that the 1st image is smooth and the 2nd one is rough?

EDIT: I also want Matlab to be able to detect which edges are smooth and rough in the same image:

Answer (score 0):

If your images of interest are all of the same type as you showed, a simple approach could be (Image Processing Toolbox needed):

```
smooth = imread('smooth.png');

figure(1);
imshow(smooth);

smoothOpened = (smooth, ones(21));

figure(2);
imshow(smoothOpened);

smoothDiff = smooth - smoothOpened;

figure(3),
imshow(smoothDiff);

smoothDifference = sum(smoothDiff(:) > 0)

rough = imread('rough.png');

figure(4);
imshow(rough);

roughOpened = imopen(rough, ones(21));

figure(5);
imshow(roughOpened);

roughDiff = rough - roughOpened;

figure(6);
imshow(roughDiff);

roughDifference = sum(roughDiff(:) > 0)

smoothDifference =  2592
roughDifference =  11328
```

(Image outputs omitted here.)

Basically, we do morphological opening (`imopen`) to get rid of the "spikes". You can vary the shape and size of the structuring element. I used a simple 21 x 21 square here. Afterwards, we determine the difference between the original and the "opened" image. The number of pixels greater 0 can be an approximation for the "smoothness" or "roughness". As I said, this approach might only work for images as shown in the question.

One should use binary images, so that `imopen` also generates binary images. For the sake of simplicity, I used the general `uint8` version, resulting in pixel values 0 < x < 255 in the `xxxOpened` images.

Comment: Should still work from my point of view. Extract both structures (if not overlapping), and apply my solution for both individually. Of course, you have to set up some kind of ratio for the amount of "difference values" with respect to the size of the single structures to compare results.